# How to use single & multiple comment line in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm new in twig project. I need to comment some code like // or /**/. how to use comment in twig?

```
    {%if role=3 %}
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
           <select multiple class="form-control"  id="path_attachment" name="path_attachment[]"></select>
        </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please, reformulate your question, tell us what you try, what you get and what you expect.

Answer (score 10):

```
{# Commented Code in Twig #}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 7):

**Comments :)**

To comment out one or more lines of code (or part of a line)

Use the {# ..... #} syntax.

**For example:**

Single-line comment:

```
{# This will be a comment #}
```

Some part of the line:

```
<p>You can also comment out {# part of a line #}.</p>
```

Multi-line comment:

```
{# This will be a 
multi-line
comment. 
#}
```

Comments aren't just useful for writing notes about your code. You can also cause blocks of code to not be executed. Any **Twig** code that is between comment tags will not be executed or outputted.

```
{# The following code will not be executed and nothing will be outputted
{% if category.posts %}
    This category has posts
{% endif %}
#}
```

Answer (score 6):

twig command keyword is #. using inside of {# and end with #}. below is your needed answer.

```
    {#%if role=3 %}
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
           <select multiple class="form-control"  id="path_attachment" name="path_attachment[]"></select>
        </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
{% endif %#}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also, configure a shortcut with your IDE / Editor for commenting many lines.

In PhpStorm, I use ***Ctrl + b*** to accomplish this.

Comment: The question states how to comment code in Twig, not how to comment out code in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the html comment tags `<!--`   `-->`

Especially if you want to comment out a block of code that already includes a twig comment.
It will ignore the existing {# #} tags.
;)

`<!-- {# some existing comment using twig comment tags #} -->` **is possible**

`{#   {# some existing comment using twig comment tags #}  #}` **is not**